# Any api routes does not work in laravel project

Tags: laravel

Any of my laravel project api routes does not work. It returns this

my test route:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return 'test';
});
```

When I open route in my browser directly (any routes even a test route):

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError

with this error: laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php:29
```

my SessionGuard file:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\CurrentDeviceLogout;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\OtherDeviceLogout;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Validated;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\SupportsBasicAuth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cookie\QueueingFactory as CookieJar;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use RuntimeException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;

class SessionGuard implements StatefulGuard, SupportsBasicAuth // line 29
{
```

In my artisan console:

```
PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '' (ASCII=1) state=0 in \vendor\laravel\framewor
k\src\Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers.php on line 36
```

My project was working without any problem, and I **didnt change anything** in my project, but today I have this problem.

**Update:**

When I create new route, it returns 404 error, cant define new routes, and **my old routes still returns old error even when I delete them!**

Comment: Can you show us the whole error stack trace not just a few snippets of it?

Comment: This is the whole error stack, its only show me what I post it, without any extra. (even my browser page title has no words)

Comment: Try running `php artisan route:clear` and check if you still get the error.

Comment: Thanks, I use this command so now I can access to my new routes but still getting the error

Comment: What version of Laravel are you running? `php artisan --version`  And what version of PHP do you have installed? `php -v`

Comment: Laravel Framework 8.64.0 with 7.4.21 php, before the error I use Cache remember method and Cache forget method with key in my controllers, and I use php artisan cache:clear, but my project was working, after restarting my system this error comes up, now I clone last version of my project without those cache things and its totally working without this error

Comment: It's good to hear that you solved your issue.